# Apache Pig floating number SUM error in precision

Tags: sum, double, apache-pig, floating

I have rows with a double values. 
The sum of them however has additional floating digits which I dont want in the output. Any idea to avoid this problem ?

```
A = LOAD 'test.csv' Using PigStorage(',') AS (
        ID: chararray,
        COST:double
);
B = GROUP A BY (ID);
C = FOREACH B GENERATE SUM(A.COST); 
STORE C INTO 'out.txt' USING PigStorage(',');
```

**INPUT FILE**

```
A,0.51
A,0.51
B,4.81
B,4.81
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT FILE**

```
A,1.02
B,9.62
```

**ACTUAL INVALID OUTPUT FILE**

```
10.020000457763672
9.619999885559082
```

Comment: you code is correct. It must give the same answer as you expect.Try to run your once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `C = FOREACH B GENERATE ROUND(SUM(A.COST)*100.0)/100.0;`

**EDIT**
 It works, see below the output

[image]

Comment: @math_law I've edited the answer to include the output.